# Android Error: Unable to merge dex

Tags: android, merge, android-gradle-plugin

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

I got the following error

This is my build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ryan.mychatapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.2.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.1'
    compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
}
```

This is my another build gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I already added  multiDexEnabled true, but the error keep popping up. I already tried, clean and rebuild, but none of it is working, what should I do? I not sure what is wrong with my gradle? I pasted my whole gradle in this post.

Let me know which part should I change

Comment: did you manage to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing implementation and compile, use simply implementation for all your dependencies as compile has been deprecated. Also update your gradle plugin.

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }


dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.2.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.1'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
}
```

Comment: by adding classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'